# iPhone 4S speaker not working for apps but works for ringer

Tags: iphone, hardware

I have an iPhone 4S and the speakers are not working for applications. The speaker works when doing voice calls on speaker phone, adjusting the ringer, and other default things.

However, when trying to have audio for YouTube and other applications it does not work.

It wasn't working for IOS 6.1.3 and I have now upgraded it to 7.0.4 with no luck. I then restored again with no luck.

I believe the fact that it works for the speaker phone and ringtone would suggest it is not a hardware problem but a software problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This might be a silly question, but have you set your "vibrate" switch away from the silent mode? (pull it towards you?) And you've surely tried using the volume buttons to turn it up. (Silly questions, but might be worth adding these details to the question)

Comment: @user67361  how you fix this problem  my vibrate mode is off and speaker is working while calling but now worked when calling through apps

Answer (score 3):

I had this very same issue, after some research on the [Apple Discussions forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3516481?start=45&tstart=0) I found out that it was due to either the docking connector at at the bottom or the headphone port either needing to be cleaned or that one or both may have been damaged. If you have tried using headphones and can adjust the sound with headphones in this would lead me to believe that this is indeed the most likely scenario.

In my case it was likely to be water related (as my flatmate didn't screw the top on the water bottle in my gym bag and the water got in my phone). If it has been water damaged then you might be able to get some of the water out using silica gel (available on Amazon). Place the silica gel around the powered down phone and seal tightly and leave for at least 48hrs. This should absorb some of the water.

If the damage hasn't be caused by water, you could try cleaning the headphone port and dock connector. You can use a soft bristle toothbrush for the dock connector, again while the phone is off, and give it a decent clean, being careful not to press too hard. You could also use some alcohol here but be careful not to use too much.

The headphone connector can be cleaned using a Q-Tip and alcohol while the phone is off. It needs to be left to dry before turning it on again but it should clean up the headphone port nicely.

If none of this works then it is likely that there is something else wrong with the phone and it would probably be best to take it to Apple, or a third party repair company for them to have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue due to exposure to water.  Dried out the device as best as i could.  Sound would still not work, expect for ringer.  I powered off the device, sprayed the docking connector with electrical contact cleaner, then took a piece of a business card with a small piece of paper towel over it and cleaned the docking connector.  After that, my volume controls and everything work as they should.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving your wifi and going outside to use cellular data seems to snap the sound back on, for me at least. It might also work in reverse--cellular to wifi.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on an iPhone 4S starting in March 2015 - as others note I thought was hardware as reinitialization of the phone did nothing but installation of iOS9 did fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happend with my phone too! Steam caused it!

I kept my phone out in sun for approximately 5 hours, in switch off condition! Then again did the same thing next day! And it started working but after using it for 2-3 hours it started giving same problem! 
Then I kept in the rice jar (with rice, completely dipped in rice) for 48 hours! Now it works fine.